# Slicing NumPy array with array of start and end indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

**The question**

How to efficiently slice a multidimensional `np.array` using a second `np.array` of similar dimensions, containing start and stop indices?

**Minimal working example**

I have a 4d array of values I would like to slice e.g.:

```
shape = np.array([[3,3], [5,5]])
arr = np.arange(np.prod(shape), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape.flatten())
```

Which is in this case all integers between 0 and 225 in a (3,3,5,5) matrix.

Additionally, I have a list of indices:

```
idxs = np.broadcast_to(np.array([[1,1], [4,3]]), (*shape[0],2,2))
rand = np.random.randint(-1, 2, shape[0])
idxs = idxs + np.broadcast_to(rand[:,:,None,None], (*shape[0],2,2))
```

This is a 4d array of 2d coordinates:

```
np.array([[r1, c1], [r2,c2]])
```

where `[r1, r2]` and `[c1,c2]` indicate the rows and columns I want to slice between, respectively. Even though some randomness is applied, I can guarantee that all elements of `idxs` span a slice of equal dimensions (a 3x2 matrix in this case). Alternatively, the shape can be calculated using:

```
extent = np.min(idxs[:,:,1] - idxs[:,:,0], axis=(0,1))
```

**Simple Python implementation**

This function achieves what I want but does so with a slow, regular Python `for` loop.

```
def sliceMultiDim(arr: np.ndarray, idxs: np.ndarray, extent: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    sliced = np.zeros((*arr.shape[:2], *extent))        
    for row in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for col in range(arr.shape[1]):
            sub = arr[row,col]
            idx = idxs[row,col]
            sliced[row,col] = sub[idx[0,0] : idx[1,0], idx[0,1] : idx[1,1]]
    return sliced
```

**Benchmark**

Defining the [vectorized solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77875242/15203390).

```
def sliceMultiDimVect(arr: np.ndarray, idxs: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    # Calculating the minimum extent of the sliding window.
    extent = np.min(idxs[:,:,1] - idxs[:,:,0], axis=(0,1))
    # Create a six dimensional view of (in this case) all shape `(3, 2)` windows.
    windowed = swv(arr, tuple(extent), axis=(2, 3))
    # The top right corners of each slice.
    # These index the required slices directly in `windowed`.
    r1, c1 = idxs[:, :, 0, 0], idxs[:, :, 0, 1]
    # Advanced index grid for the first two dimensions.
    h, w = np.indices(arr.shape[:2], sparse=True)
    return windowed[h, w, r1, c1]
```

When bumping up the size of the problem, the vectorized solution is about 8x faster* than my naive implementation, according to the following simple benchmarking script.

```
import timeit
# Setup 100 million values in 100 arrays.
shape = np.array([[10,10], [10000,10000]])
arr = np.arange(np.prod(shape), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape.flatten())
# Slicing 1 million values.
idxs = np.broadcast_to(np.array([[0,0], shape[1]//10]), (*shape[0],2,2))
rand = np.random.randint(0, shape[1,0]//10, shape[0])
idxs = idxs + np.broadcast_to(rand[:,:,None,None], (*shape[0],2,2))
def non_vect():
    sliceMultiDim(arr, idxs)
def vect():
    sliceMultiDimVect(arr, idxs)
print("non_vect:", timeit.timeit("non_vect()", setup="from __main__ import non_vect", number=100))
print("vect:", timeit.timeit("vect()", setup="from __main__ import vect", number=100))
```

| Solution | Time [s] | Relative time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| vect | 8.430499400012195 | 1 |
| non_vect | 64.53972959998646 | ~7.7 |

---

* Run on an Intel Core i7-1185G7 @ 3.00 GHz machine.

Comment: You have an added layer of that `sub` indexing, but the usual suggestion in SO like this is to create the equivalent selection with `advanced indexing` arrays.  There are many such SO, especially for getting multiple slices from a 1d array.

Comment: I assume you are referring to [this section](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) of the official NumPy docs? If I understand well, this would boil down to, rather than supplying a start and end index, creating a `np.arange(idx_start, idx_end)` for each index pair. Is such a range of indices equally efficient as a slice (`arr[[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]]` vs `arr[0:4, 4:8]`)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: To get the 2d block you have to use `arr[[[0],[1],[2],[3]], [4,5,6,7]]`.  For selections of the same size from a 1d array, you can use `linspace` to create a 2d indexing array (to get all at once).  It would be harder to construct such an array for your 2d blocks.  The `sliding_window_view` is a better way of constructing and selecting the desired blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built in function for this, because nothing requires the indices in your `idxs` array to span an equal shape across all slices of the original array. If there were different shapes, then the function would produce a "ragged" array, which is not allowed.

The fact that you can guarantee that each slice will be of shape `extent` allows us some trickery! In short: create a view of all `extent` shape windows of your array `arr`, and index into that array with arrays of `r1` and `c`.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view as swv

# the original setup
shape = np.array([[3,3], [5,5]])
arr = np.arange(np.prod(shape), dtype=np.uint8).reshape(shape.flatten())

idxs = np.broadcast_to(np.array([[1,1], [4,3]]), (*shape[0],2,2))
rand = np.random.randint(-1, 2, shape[0])
idxs = idxs + np.broadcast_to(rand[:,:,None,None], (*shape[0],2,2))

extent = np.min(idxs[:,:,1] - idxs[:,:,0], axis=(0,1))

# Create a six dimensional view of (in this case) all shape `(3, 2)` windows.
windowed = swv(arr, tuple(extent), axis=(2, 3))

# The top right corners of each slice.
# These index the required slices directly in `windowed`.
r1, c1 = idxs[:, :, 0, 0], idxs[:, :, 0, 1]

# Advanced index grid for the first two dimensions.
h, w = np.indices(arr.shape[:2], sparse=True)

out = windowed[h, w, r1, c1]
```

As a one liner:

```
out = swv(arr, tuple(extent), axis=(2, 3))[*np.indices(arr.shape[:2], sparse=True), idxs[:, :, 0, 0], idxs[:, :, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: what is `extent` in this code ?  it is mentioned in the answer but undefined in the code.

Comment: It's in OP's question: an array with the values [3, 2]

Comment: if you could add it to the code in the question, that would add clarity. I tried to reproduce the answer (which i believe would be a good answer) and could not.

Comment: I've added it! But I think it might be easier to grasp if you define extent beforehand as a tuple of (height, width), rather than determining it from the indices

Comment: I agree! Additionally, with a given `extent`, the guarantee of a constant span is more readily enforceable. We can just get rid of the end coordinates and calculate them from the start plus the span.